# Implementing an upvote/downvote system in Javascript but can't get the math right

Tags: javascript, jquery, vote

```
var $arrow       = $(this);
var $sibling     = $arrow.siblings('span.arrow');
var $score       = $arrow.siblings('span.score');

var vote         = $arrow.hasClass('up') ? 'up' : 'down';
var alreadyVoted = $sibling.hasClass('voted');

if (!USER_LOGGED_IN)
{
    alert('You must be logged into vote');
}
else if (!$arrow.hasClass('voted'))
{
    if (alreadyVoted)
        $sibling.removeClass('voted');

    $arrow.addClass('voted');
    $score[0].innerHTML = parseInt($score[0].innerHTML) + ((vote == 'up') ? 1 : -1);
}
```

I have an upvote and downvote button. A 'current score' is shown next to these buttons which I would like to increment/decrement when a vote is cast.

For example, if they load the page and see the score is `200`. When they upvote, the score will change to `201`. When they downvote, the score needs to change to `199`. Why? Because if they downvote after upvotting (change their mind) then the vote needs to go from the original score. Not the new score they created by upvotting.

Basically, if they upvote and then downvote, the score, currently, goes back to the original score. Their vote isn't cast.

I'm having trouble making this work so their vote is cast...

Comment: Thank you so much for the code in the question. I am trying to implement something like that now too, but I'm not so experienced with jQuery and couldn't select the right elements.

Answer (score 3):

change this bit:

```
parseInt($score[0].innerHTML) + ((vote == 'up') ? 1 : -1);
```

to this:

```
parseInt($score[0].innerHTML) + ((vote == 'up') ? 1 : -1) + ((alreadyVoted) ? ((vote == 'up') ? 1 : -1) : 0);
```

Its verbose, but it will work in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is working as expected. If you upvote, that's +1. If you then downvote (decrement) it's minus one, and the result of n + 1 - 1 should be n. They should have to downvote again if they want to achieve a true downvote.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like if the user has already voted up (so vote = 1) and then they click the down arrow instead, you want vote = -1 instead of vote = 0 (much as StackOverflow does it). If so, you'll need to explicitly detect that condition in your script, something like:

```
var voteValue = parseInt($score[0].innerHTML, 10);
if (alreadyVoted) {
    $sibling.removeClass('voted');
    // Undo the previous vote
    voteValue += $sibling.hasClass('up') ? -1 : 1;
}

// Apply the new vote
$arrow.addClass('voted');
voteValue += (vote == 'up') ? 1 : -1;
$score[0].innerHTML = voteValue;
```

Or, of course, if it really is either "up" or "down" (like SO), it gets a **lot** simpler:

```
if (alreadyVoted)
    $sibling.removeClass('voted');

$arrow.addClass('voted');
$score[0].innerHTML = vote == 'up' ? 1 : -1;
```

...since there's really no need for adding/subtracting at all.